# Email, Phone and Video problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video, email, phone

I have these issues with my Meizu Pro5: 15.04 OTA-13

Unable to answer phone - Answer phone buttons do not work.
Unable to use Dekko and Email
Unable to record Video

Two of the three are what a smart phone is all about. Any solutions to ANY of these problems would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with Dekko on Meizu phones and the developer is working to fix them (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1568350) When trying to answer a phone call, are you swiping to the right or just pressing the centre button?  What do you mean by 'Email'.  I can't find a bug report for video - you can report this problem (and any other bugs) here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers

Comment: @Tony - I was pressing the buttons. I took the hint and swiped right BINGO, the phone answered, However, being that the  phone was on stand-by, i was unable to enter the pass code before it hung up. The fingerprint entry would have been faster,unfortunately, i nave not been able to get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Answering the Phone - Swipe right instead of pressing button. Make sure you do not need a pass code or phrase to wake up the phone.
Second:eMail - Dekko is a work in progress. Wait for fix.
Third: Video Playback - Bug report filed for video play-back on phone. Work-around = Copy mp4 file onto your PC and watch it there. ALSO:Take video in Wide Screen,horizontal mode only.